# Dirft Tube Linac Diameter

Tags: electromagnetism, accelerator-physics

How to calculate dirft tube cavity diameter. Why it's so big. For electromagnetic frequency?

[image]

Comment: Google "drift tube linac diameter design parameters" and many papers will come up.